# tokenize string in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have one file contianing below line :

> MO                                                      Attribute
>   Value
>   ================================================================================================================= Sctp=CTRL-2_10.76.32.6_10.76.32.69
>   maxIncomingStream 17 Sctp=CTRL-5_10.76.32.7_10.76.32.70
>   maxIncomingStream 17
>   ================================================================================================================= Total: 2 MOs
>
> MGW02NN> get .  maxOutgoingStream
>
> 141202-11:53:55 10.76.128.12 10.0s MGW_NODE_MODEL_C_1_76
>   stopfile=/tmp/22309
>   ================================================================================================================= MO                                                      Attribute
>   Value
>   ================================================================================================================= Sctp=CTRL-2_10.76.32.6_10.76.32.69
>   maxOutgoingStream 17 Sctp=CTRL-5_10.76.32.7_10.76.32.70
>   maxOutgoingStream 17
>   ================================================================================================================= Total: 2 MOs

i am searching line wich matches to the string maxOutgoingStream ,i am able to do it i am trying 2 token of line maxOutgoingStream 17 to store in a array ,but i am not able to store both tokens i am able to store only one token either maxOutgoingStream or 17.

i tried with the following code:

```
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "associationMaxRtx maxIncomingStream maxOutgoingStream initialAdRecWin maxUserdataSize mBuffer nThreshold PathMaxRtx maxInitialRtrAtt minimumRto maximumRto initialRto rtoAlphaIndex tSack" C:\Users\ephajin\logs.txt') do (
    set /A count+=1
     set "array[!count!]=%%a"
)
```

please tell me solution how can store both together in an array as maxOutgoingStream 17.

Answer (score 1):

to use more tokens, just increase the `%%` variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,5,9 delims= " %%a in (...) do echo 2=%%a, 3=%%b, 5=%%c, 9=%%d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i want to store both the token eg:maxIncomingStream 17 in to a variable,is there any way to do it.

Comment: `set "one=%%a"` and `set "two=%%b"`? or `set "var=%%a %%b"`?